# Safely using TRUNCATE with active AFTER INSERT triggers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, timescaledb

**TLDR:** In PostgreSQL what would be a safe way to clean the staging table or use `TRUNCATE`, ensuring the `AFTER INSERT` trigger is finished processing all rows before `TRUNCATE` is executed?

Can I rely on the `TRUNCATE` statement to wait for any potentially active triggers to finish processing all batch inserted rows before deleting them?

**Details:**
I have a `staging_table` where I insert data continuously 24/7 using the PostgreSQL COPY tool (timescaledb-parallel-copy), with 32 parallel workers up to 120k ROW/s. This data is transferred from the `staging_table` to the final `time_series_table` using an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that performs an `UPSERT` operation for each row. I clean the `staging_table` running the `TRUNCATE` statement as a scheduled job every night.

I understand the `TRUNCATE` statement uses an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, meaning that this mode guarantees that the holder is the only transaction accessing the table in any way. And waits for any current active processes to finish before executing.

For example, when inserting data into the table in 10k row batches of 120k ROW/s, I'm not exactly sure how the `AFTER INSERT` trigger that performs an `UPSERT` operation behaves internally as it processes rows one by one. So, I'm concerned about whether the `TRUNCATE` statement might execute before the `AFTER INSERT` trigger has processed all the new rows.

My understanding is that when I insert for example a batch of 10k rows, it is treated as a single transaction. Therefore, the `AFTER INSERT` `FOR EACH ROW` trigger, which executes the `UPSERT` operation as one transaction one row at a time, meaning that if any single row in the batch encounters an issue, the entire batch will fail. Also, I assume the entire batch must be fully processed by the trigger before a TRUNCATE operation gets executed.

Simplified `AFTER INSERT` `UPSERT` example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_example_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Proceed with upsert into a time_series target table
    INSERT INTO time_series_table (id, time, value, status)
    VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.time, NEW.value, NEW.status)
    ON CONFLICT (id, time)
    DO UPDATE SET
        value = EXCLUDED.value,
        status = EXCLUDED.status
    WHERE (
        -- Update unless status_code indicates a locked state
        time_series_table.status <> 'locked'
        )
        -- AND if the new data differs in value or status
        AND (
        time_series_table.value IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.value OR
        time_series_table.status IS DISTINCT FROM EXCLUDED.status
        );

    -- Return the row to indicate successful processing
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_upsert_example
AFTER INSERT ON staging_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION upsert_example_function();
```

Comment: Why not use a `FOR EACH STATEMENT` trigger along with a transition table per *Example 43.7.* here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-AUDIT-TRANSITION-EXAMPLE). Then you process the entire batch at a time instead of row by row.  Then the window for the TRUNCATE operation should be at least a little bigger. Obviously, this should be tested.

Comment: Because of the access exclusive lock, there can not be any other transaction using this table. Triggers are part of a transaction, so all after insert triggers must be completed as well.

Comment: By the way, why do you need the TRUNCATE? You could use a RETURN NULL in a BEFORE trigger (change of logic needed!) or a DELETE for the record in your AFTER trigger. In both cases there will be no record at the end of the transaction. And there is nothing to truncate anymore.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Using `RETURN NULL` in a `BEFORE` trigger sounds interesting, but I'm not sure how I would implement an `UPSERT` with that approach. Currently, the AFTER INSERT trigger performs an `UPSERT` operation on the final time_series_table, which is why I'm using the staging table including additional conditional logic to keep the application code clean.


`DELETE` in `AFTER INSERT` could be an option, but that would probably slow down the ingestion.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, I would love to process the entire batch at a time instead of row by row, as that would speed up the ingestion. However, I'm not quite sure how to implement an `UPSERT` in this approach, according to your Example 43.7. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I am not seeing anything in your question that refers to an `UPSERT`. You will need to add, to your question,  an explanation of what you mean by this?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Refactored the question according to your feedback and included an example about the `UPSERT` operation.

Comment: 1) Per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): *The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null.* `RETURN NEW;` is not doing what you think it is. 2) You could adapt this per the *Example 43.7*. Substitute the  `NEW`  values with `new_table` values.